# centos server hanging every night

Tags: centos

Centos server hanging every night and have to reboot every morning.

I am reading log files to figure this out. I find a lot of following entries in /var/log/message log.

could any of you please explain, what exactly these are?

```
Jul 28 09:47:12 snmpd[2352]: twRaidUnitConfig_get: tw_get_unit_configuration returns 00000002 (00000001) 
Jul 28 09:47:14 snmpd[2352]: twRaidUnitTable_cache_load: Error getting Unit Stripe Size 32767 
Jul 28 09:47:14 snmpd[2352]: twRaidUnitTable_cache_load: Error getting Unit ReadCache State 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type of RAID this is, but...

Judging from this information, if I were you I would check the state of the drives in your array.  I've seen servers stop responding during high reads (backups, etc.) with a single drive bad in RAID 5, for example.

Comment: Looks like a 3ware something or other to me.